# different sequence same field in indexing are different

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

I have creat two indexes . The question is that `[BCLIENT], [NAME]`  And in Second `[NAME], [BCLIENT]` Is that both will equal or it will work different manner , because i change the sequence in the indexing .

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [bclient] ON [dbo].[client] 
(
    [BCLIENT] ASC,
    [NAME] ASC
) 
GO
```

And Second index is Like this

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RDATE] ON [dbo].[client] 
(
    [NAME] ASC,
    [BCLIENT] ASC
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they will not be equal, and will not act the same.

I always refer to the phone book example as a good reference for this.

Lets asy you have a query as follows

```
SELECT *
FROm PhoneBook
WHERE Surname = 'TADA'
```

and you have an index create as `Surname, Name`, the index would be properly used, but if the index was in the order `Name, Surname` the query engine would not be able to use the index, and would have to do an index scan/ table scan/ clustered index scan.